# How can you place a block on a block with right click action without using shift?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So we all know if you want to place a block on an existing block that has a right click action (chest, dropper, etc), it will open up the UI for the existing block and the way to get around it is to hold shift. But in [this video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbFtJJc_Sok&t=2m20s), at 2:20 he places a dropper onto a chest without holding shift as he's clearly floating in creative mode and doesn't hit the floor, how can you do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can't place a block on a block with a right click action without pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>.

However, when you fly in creatve mode and hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd> at the same time, then you will stay at the same hight, so it's possible to place a block on a block with a right click action while floating in creative mode.

Comment: I wondered the same for a long time, but apparently some people have really mastered pressing those two keys in the exact same frame, so you don't even see any movement. In the linked video there is actually some movement.